# Извлечь _id всех записей в плоский массив (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

В `mongodb` содержатся такие структуры:

```
[{
  "BestOfferEnabled": "true",
  "AutoPayEnabled": "true",
  "CategoryID": "171784",
  "CategoryLevel": "4",
  "CategoryName": "Seller Category 3",
  "CategoryParentID": "171781",
  "LeafCategory": "true",
  "_id": 171784
},
{
  "BestOfferEnabled": "true",
  "AutoPayEnabled": "true",
  "CategoryID": "171785",
  "CategoryLevel": "4",
  "CategoryName": "Seller Category 4",
  "CategoryParentID": "171781",
  "LeafCategory": "true",
  "_id": 171785
},
{
  "BestOfferEnabled": "true",
  "AutoPayEnabled": "true",
  "CategoryID": "171786",
  "CategoryLevel": "4",
  "CategoryName": "Seller Category 5",
  "CategoryParentID": "171781",
  "LeafCategory": "true",
  "_id": 171786
}]
```

Как получить список `_id` в виде массива `[171784, 171785, 171786]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку значение отличается для каждого документа нужно использовать метод [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

```
> db.collection.distinct('_id')
[ 171784, 171785, 171786 ]
```

Если значение не отличается, нужно вызвать [`.map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map) метод.

```
db.collection.find().map(function(doc) {
    return doc._id;
})
```

Результат:

```
[ 171784, 171785, 171786 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Это у вас массив в json формате. Массив содержит в себе объекты. Обращаться свойствам объектов в данном случае так:

```js
var str='[{\
  "BestOfferEnabled": "true",\
  "AutoPayEnabled": "true",\
  "CategoryID": "171784",\
  "CategoryLevel": "4",\
  "CategoryName": "Seller Category 3",\
  "CategoryParentID": "171781",\
  "LeafCategory": "true",\
  "_id": 171784\
},\
{\
  "BestOfferEnabled": "true",\
  "AutoPayEnabled": "true",\
  "CategoryID": "171785",\
  "CategoryLevel": "4",\
  "CategoryName": "Seller Category 4",\
  "CategoryParentID": "171781",\
  "LeafCategory": "true",\
  "_id": 171785\
},\
{\
  "BestOfferEnabled": "true",\
  "AutoPayEnabled": "true",\
  "CategoryID": "171786",\
  "CategoryLevel": "4",\
  "CategoryName": "Seller Category 5",\
  "CategoryParentID": "171781",\
  "LeafCategory": "true",\
  "_id": 171786\
}]';

var arr=JSON.parse(str);
alert(arr[0]._id);
alert(arr[1]._id);
alert(arr[2]._id);
```

**UPD**
Получение массива из _id

```
...
var arr=JSON.parse(str);
var arrez =[];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrez.push(arr[i]._id);
}
console.log(arrez);
```

Comment: Это понятно. Таких объектов у меня 20000. Как получить их _id в виде массива?

Comment: @Oceinic, обновил.

Comment: Мне хотелось бы решить эту проблему стандартными средствами mongodb. Поэтому оставлю пока этот вопрос открытым

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я не совсем понял вопрос (при чем тут Group_concat), но, судя по задаче, Вам подойдет простая команда поиска, с уточнением набора возвращаемых полей

```
db.collection.find(null, {_id:1})
```